# What is OnActionExecuting defined for in ASP.NET-MVC's AccountController?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The project template for ASP.NET-MVC includes an AccountController that contains the following piece of code

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity is WindowsIdentity) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Windows authentication is not supported.");
    }
}
```

What is it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For information on the method, see [the MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx).

The override you are referring to is throwing an exception if the website has been set up to use Windows authentication, in effect preventing this being used as a method of authentication.

Comment: do you know why it is not supported?

Comment: It's just the way the template is set up. You can use Windows authentication with MVC if you want.  See http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-18-cs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The template is set up for FormsAuthentication.  This ensures that a WindowsIdentity cannot successfully authenticate.